# How change jquery version with rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require active_scaffold
```

on client

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/active_scaffold.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/jquery.editinplace.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/date_picker_bridge.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/draggable_lists.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/active_scaffold.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

/assets/jquery.js?body=1 contains jquery of v1.9.0 but I wish to have a 1.6 version of jquery.

**How define jquery version with rails asset pipeline?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Support of jQuery for Rails comes from the gem [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails)

When you do a `rails new {app}` it would by default have included this gem. and the respective include statements in application.js

1. From [jquery-rails github README](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/README.md) the latest version supports.

   jQuery 1.9.0
2. If support for 1.6.2 is fine then you can look at [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/pull/11) to see when it got included, and include that version of jquery-rails. Mostly `1.0.12`
3. As a last resort - it would be better if you remove this gem and directly import these into `assets/javascripts` or reference them from the web.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jquery-rails, here's the mapping ([VERSIONS.md](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md)) of the bundled jQuery versions to the jquery-rails versions.