# How to update to Jquery 1.11.1 to 1.11.3 in a Rails Project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have to upgrade my jQuery in Rails project, the target version is 1.11.3, I see jquery-rails gem not have this version
Is there any way?
Thank You

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459161/how-change-jquery-version-with-rails-asset-pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts shows that jQuery is updated to 1.11.3. Try `bundle update jquery-rails` Check [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263150/update-just-one-gem-with-bundler) for more details

Comment: Not works, i have a tried update, my version jquery-rails is 4.0.4, but i comprobe te version jquery, returns 1.11.1